# Error while installing ROS Base Install from SVN on Ubuntu (BeagleBoard)

Tags: ros, beagleboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS from SVN on my BeagleBoard (with Ubuntu 10.04 on it) using instructions from [Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu/SVN). I previously installed the ROS-only version without problems. Now, as I wanted to install the kinect-stack, I wanted to "upgrade" to ros-base. But after executing

```
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=cturtle&variant=base&overlay=no"
```

I got:

```
ERROR: woah, unknown installation method hg not installed, cannot create a hg vcs client
```

Any clues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9122/error-while-installing-ros-base-install-from-svn-on-ubuntu-(beagleboard)/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like you need to install mercurial.

---

Originally posted by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) with karma: 411 on 2011-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-18**:
Thanks, whatever it is, sudo apt-get install hgsvn seems to have solved my problem.